# Using a string from a custom field within a link

Tags: php, custom-field, plugin-types

I want to show the image only if there is info in the field. And the link around the image uses the info in the field.  The mailto: field is coming up blank. So I'm guessing/hoping I'm doing something wrong with the way I'm printing/calling it.  I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
<?php $email = types_render_field ("email");
          if ( $email ) { ?>
           <a href="mailto:<?php $email ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/icon-email.gif" width="24" height="24" /></a>
<?php } ?>
```

In case it's relevant, I'm using the Types plugin to create my custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

Change,

```
<?php $email ?>
```

to...

```
<?php echo $email; ?>
```

as you need to `echo` the result of what's held within `$email` as the function `types_render_field` would be using `return` within the function (if you dig into its core) to return the data instead of directly printing it to screen.

```
<?php $email = types_render_field ("email");
          if ( $email ) { ?>
           <a href="mailto:<?php echo $email; ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/icon-email.gif" width="24" height="24" /></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. When I echo it, it pulls it out of the href link and displays email@address.com" (with the quote at the end, from the href code.

Any idea how to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Sorry, add a semi-colon `;` after your variable declaration - so `<?php echo $email; ?>` (snippet updated)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It had to do with the way the custom field had been created. When it was an "email field", it gave me that big mess. When I made it just a single line text field, it was fine.

Comment: Hmm probably shouldn't have made a difference, it was more likely the missing semi-colon that was causing the improper output as mentioned in my update below.

Comment: the semi-colon and echo helped with the field return, thanks. But the new problem that presented itself -- the inability for the field's value to exist within an href tag -- was fixed by changing the field type.

Comment: Peculiar to say the least. It shouldn't have an effect on printing the value within a href attribute, however, changing the field type still suffices. I wonder if adding `true` as in `$email = types_render_field('email', true);` would have any bearing? That aside, if the problem is now solved for you that's great, then you cane mark and close out this question.